# Failed to build ARIMA forecast: not enough data points: length=13, r=7

Tags: arima

I'm working on a project about rides. I want to take all the rides that have been taken on a certain day, to perform a forecast.

So, for example, i want to store in an array the number of rides i had for the last 24 Mondays. Like:

```
double[] array = { 1, 4, 2, 6, 4, ...}
```

To do this, i have to use a code provided by another guy working in my office.

The code he made to perform the forecast is this:

```
 public List<String> performArimaForecast(double[] daily) {
        int p = 1;
        int d = 0;
        int q = 1;
        int P = 1;
        int D = 1;
        int Q = 1;
        int m = 5;
        int forecastSize = 3;

        ForecastResult forecastResult = Arima.forecast_arima(daily, forecastSize, new ArimaParams(p, d, q, P, D, Q, m));


        double[] forecastData = forecastResult.getForecast();
        double[] uppers = forecastResult.getForecastUpperConf();
        double[] lowers = forecastResult.getForecastLowerConf();

        double rmse = forecastResult.getRMSE();

        double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (double valore : uppers) {
            if (valore > max)
                max = valore;
        }
        for (double valore : lowers) {
            if (valore > max)
                max = valore;
        }

        double[] uppers_norm = new double[uppers.length];
        double[] lowers_norm = new double[lowers.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < uppers.length; i++) {
            uppers_norm[i] = Math.round(uppers[i] * 100) / max;
            uppers_norm[i] = Math.round(uppers_norm[i] * 100.0) / 100.0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lowers.length; i++) {
            lowers_norm[i] = Math.round(lowers[i] * 100) / max;
            lowers_norm[i] = Math.round(lowers_norm[i] * 100.0) / 100.0;
        }

        List<String> forecasts = new ArrayList<>();

        if (forecastData.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < forecastSize; i++) {
                double forecast = forecastData[i];
                String forecastString = "TEMPORAL CYCLE " + (i + 1) + ": \n" + "EXPECTED REQUESTS: " + Math.round(forecast) + "\n";

                if (i < uppers.length && i < lowers.length) {

                    double upper = uppers_norm[i];
                    double lower = lowers_norm[i];
                    double media = (double) Math.round(lower + upper) / 2;

                    forecastString += "AVERAGE HAPPENING PROBABILITY: \n";
                    forecastString += "[" + media + "%]\n";
                    forecastString += "RMSE: " + rmse + " \n";
                } else {
                    forecastString += "Data not available.";
                }
                forecasts.add(forecastString);
            }
        } else {
            forecasts.add("No forecast available for this day.");
        }
        return forecasts;
    }
```

Now, i have a Map stored in a MongoDB array, which stores for every day of a week the dates and their corresponding number of requests.

For example:

```
MONDAY: {

     "12/11/23": 7
     "5/11/23": 0
     ...
and so on
```

Now, this database stores dates for the last 6 months. So, i will have 24 rows for every day of the week.

This is the code i implemented that gets the zones (which is the main collection of this db: a zone has an id and the map i showed previously), cycle through the map and passes it to the ARIMA forecasting method:

```
public Map<String, Map<DayOfWeek, List<String>>> NEWprocessDataDB() {

        Map<String, Map<DayOfWeek, List<String>>> sortedForecastsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();


        List<Zone> zoneList = zoneRepository.findAll();

        for (Zone zones : zoneList){

            Map<DayOfWeek, Map<String, Integer>> rides = zones.getRidesPerDay();

            for (Map.Entry<DayOfWeek, Map<String, Integer>> map : rides.entrySet()) {
                DayOfWeek currDay = map.getKey();
                Map<String, Integer> ridesOfDay = map.getValue();

                double[] ridesArray = ridesOfDay.values().stream()
                        .mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)
                        .toArray();

                Map<DayOfWeek, List<String>> forecastPerDay = new HashMap<>();


                ArimaComponent arimaComponent = new ArimaComponent();
                List<String> forecasts = arimaComponent.performArimaForecast(ridesArray);

                forecastPerDay.put(currDay, forecasts);

                sortedForecastsMap.put(zones.getId(), forecastPerDay);


            }

        }

        return sortedForecastsMap;

    }
}
```

Problem is, this is the error i get:

```
Failed to build ARIMA forecast: not enough data points: length=13, r=7
```

I tried using prints to debug, and the array i pass to the method always has 24 values, as expected.

So, i think i got something wrong on how an Arima Forecast works.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [Workday's implementation](https://github.com/Workday/timeseries-forecast) of ARIMA model, which has 7 parameters, then 24 data points would not be enough information to fit any model on it. I would suggest to append/add more data points in the array named `ridesArray`.

Related GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Workday/timeseries-forecast/issues/18).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, I had already found that issue on GitHub, but i could not understand why is that, since you can use parameters to choice how many temporal lags you want... in my case, i pass every past monday of the past 6 months (thus, 24 data points). I think it should be a pretty good number of data points to perform a forecast. Is it something i can actually control, or i have to stick with it?

Comment: A forecast yes @TrySoHard, a fit? I don't feel so. Try a (few) hundred.